# Is word stemming flawed, and if so can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, bug, search

I did a search for:

> java generic method

and I got these top 4 results. SO seems to think 'generics' means the same thing as 'generate':

[image: Search engine thinks 'generics' is related to 'generate', 'generated' etc]

**I know stemming algorithms are hardly perfect**, but this seems too big of a mistake, considering it's a site about programming after all.

Using quotes obviously solves the problem but I just thought it was something I should bring to the community's attention.

Perhaps we need a built-in dictionary of 'programming words' that should not be stemmed like that?

Comment: The software runs not just Stack Overflow; there are *loads* of non-programming sites part of the network now. You can put a word in quotes to prevent stemming: `java "generic method"` gives you far more relevant results still.

Comment: I understand that, I just couldn't find any discussion on this topic so I thought it might be worth bringing up. It really doesn't seem like it stemmed the word correctly at all - `generic` is not related to `generate` at all linguistically, is it? It's just thought "the first 5 letters are the same, they must mean that" which surely isn't right.

Comment: Do a search on Google for `java generic method` and `java generate method` and you get totally different results. On SO they are identical. In my eyes _generic != generate_.

Comment: Sure, there may be problems with the stemmer; stemming is hard, but since Google is in the search business, they have got more money and time to throw at the problem.

Comment: So only search engines can do search right? That's not true. What about Quora and Reddit? They are not "in the search business" and they don't have the same problem.

Comment: Then help fix the code; the engine used is [elasticsearch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), which is Open Source.

Comment: I don't know about Quora, but reddit's search is notoriously bad. Just because they don't have this specific problem doesn't mean they are better. (Having said that, it does look like this is something that can be customized. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-stemming.html)

Comment: I agree, no site is perfect. I would imagine it's the implementation of elasticsearch, rather than elasticsearch itself. It does seem to have stemming controls to prevent overstemming like this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/controlling-stemming.html (@BilltheLizard oh, didn't see your comment til I posted mine!)

Comment: Similar question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222772/do-not-do-stemming-for-some-search-terms-https