# How does stemming actually work in the site search?

Tags: support, search

Based on [existing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+stemming) I infer that the site search does actually attempt stemming.

However, I have found that words that I would expect to match with a basic stemming algorithm often do not. For example, searching for `dict` (the name of the built-in type) can miss Python questions that only say `dictionary`, and searching for `recursive` can miss things that only say `recursion` (or vice-versa).

This seems to be the opposite of the problem described by others, e.g. [Is word stemming flawed, and if so can it be improved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275056), of overly aggressive stemming. Was the search algorithm changed?

Comment: Search has always been bad; claiming any part of it works at all is an overstatement

Comment: Might help: [HEIC is for horses…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350457/241919)

Comment: Since Elasticsearch can apparently be configured with a bunch of exceptions manually, but that's obviously a ton of work - why not outsource that to the community? Give me somewhere in the interface that I can *communicate that* `dict` and `dictionary` are related search concepts, and if multiple people agree, programmatically build it into the search stemming rules?

Comment: Part of why I'm confused is because e.g. searching for `collect` **does** find questions that only say `collecting`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they're different tokens. You can do a wildcard search (collect*). It'd be extra cool if you could do a Lucene fuzzy search as well (collecting~0.85) so you could even account for typos, but that unfortunately just seems to tokenise the weight number and use it for token matching.